# How to remove a cell and place it in another index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to remove a cell from its original index and put it in the beginning of the `tableview`, I'm trying to do this with this code but I cant, it crashes, so I need someone's help...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:important color:yellowColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState3 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {


    NSIndexPath *myindex = [self.tableview indexPathForCell:cell];
     NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]; 

    [self.tableview beginUpdates];        
    [self.tableview moveRowAtIndexPath:myindex toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
    [self.userdefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    [self.userdefaults synchronize];

    }
}
```

And this is the crash log:

```
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried -[UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]?

Comment: Going to go out on a limb and say you shouldn't remove and add cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: Great @RhythmicFistman worked perfectly but this new cell order is not savig, the tableview data is from a Array (tasks) how can I fix this? I tried adding the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say this in the comments:

> the tableview data is from a Array (tasks)

If you want to re-order the cells programmatically, then the simplest thing you could possibly do is to re-order the items in the backing array and then call:

```
[self.tableview reloadData]
```

Comment: I agree - The tableview displays your data, it isn't your data.  You can move the individual row rather than calling reloadData if you want to be more efficient, but unless you change the underlying dataSource it won't 'stick' either way

Comment: When I add [self.tableview ReloadData] the function of moving the cell does not work, I delete endUpdates and call reloadData and also dont work :S

Comment: Ready I added the reloadData at the ViewWillDissapear and works great, thanks!